send post but treated as GET?? rest-framework-bundle
I have api with django rest framework bundle
My api is like this, only accepts POST.
@api_view(["POST"])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def myapi_v1_result(request):

then I sent to this api with POST button

However it gets , Method Not allowed why does this happen?
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49305 - "POST /myapi/v1/result HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Method Not Allowed: /myapi/v1/result
WARNING:django.request:Method Not Allowed: /myapi/v1/result


Can you show us the URL pattern for this view?

this is in urls.py  path('myapi/v1/result',views.myapi_v1_result,name='myapiresult')

To my understanding, it isn't performing a GET request as an api, its part of the DRF browsable API refreshing after you've posted.
I would also highly recommend migrating to class based views.
class CustomView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CustomSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"request": self.request}
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


With this you would need a validate method in your serializer, however this is completely dependant on your needs.
You are able to forego the get function in it entirety for an actually endpoint, but whilst using the browsable api, this will fix the Method Not Allowed
